# Google Sheets OnOpen() not updating the sheet on team drive

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, eventtrigger

So I have written a script that automatically puts a date stamp in a specific cell. It works fine in my test environment (when opened normally and thru the debugger) and also works fine on the team drive when I run it thru the debugger. But it does not update the cell when run normally on the team drive. Any ideas?

```js
function onOpen() {
  var AcksSheet           = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Acks");
  var RecruiterList       = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Lists");
  var RecruitersRange     = RecruiterList.getDataRange();
  var nLenRecruitersTable = RecruitersRange.getNumRows();
  var values              = RecruitersRange.getValues();
  var email               = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var nRecruiterRow       = 0  
  for (var i = 0; i < nLenRecruitersTable; i++)
  {
    // check if active user email matches email in the recruiter table
    if (email == values[i][1])
    {
      // plus one as the range has one row header
      nRecruiterRow = i+1;
      AcksSheet.getRange(nRecruiterRow,2).setValue(new Date());
      AcksSheet.getRange(nRecruiterRow,2).setNumberFormat("MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm:ss");
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I made a copy on my personal gmail account with shareable link for anybody:

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1a4Q0ZLykfsRAgrndOsfFlCGb9eT4cI4MlNWpylY2UkA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but I was able to add a menu item to sheets using the onOpen() trigger and have it call the function

Answer (score 0):

getMail returns an empty string when it's run from an simple onOpen() trigger. Use an on open installable trigger.

From https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/base/user#getemail

> getEmail()
>
> Gets the user's email address, if available. If security policies do
>   not allow access to the user's email address, this method returns a
>   blank string. The circumstances in which the email address is
>   available vary: for example, the user's email address is not available
>   in any context that allows a script to run without that user's
>   authorization, like a simple onOpen(e) or onEdit(e) trigger, a custom
>   function in Google Sheets, or a web app deployed to "execute as me"
>   (that is, authorized by the developer instead of the user). However,
>   these restrictions generally do not apply if the developer and the
>   user belong to the same G Suite domain.

Comment: Thank you for this tidbit although since all my users are on the same G Suite domain I do not believe this is the issue. I got it working somehow, not sure exactly why it is working now. I changed the OnOpen() function to call another function rather than executing the script directly. Also added a trigger to send me an email if the OnOpen() fails. So who knows?